# AJAX wont do what I want

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Can you find the problem? It doesnt insert it into the database but I get no error.

Im a total ajax noob yes, I found this code and modified it a bit and i think it should work but it dont

rate.php

```
$v = $_GET['v'];

$conn = mysql_connect('***', '***', '***');
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('***', $conn);


$sql="INSERT INTO votes (title_id, score) VALUES (1, $v)";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

echo "Vote has been added.";

?>
```

title.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addVote(str)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","include/ajax/rate.php?v="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

Rate: <a href="#" onclick="addVote(1)">1</a> <a href="#" onclick="addVote(2)">2</a> <a href="#" onclick="addVote(3)">3</a> <a href="#" onclick="addVote(4)">4</a> <a href="#" onclick="addVote(5)">5</a>
```

Comment: You appear to have an SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Why not echo out the query you're building. RIght now it just spits out "you voted". try "You voted and the query was $sql". Then you can see if $v is showing up at all.

Comment: You should consider [jQuery](http://jquery.com) for AJAX

Comment: jQuery does make things easier, but jQuery is still JavaScript you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a timestamp to avoid caching:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","include/ajax/rate.php?t="+new Date().getTime()+"&v="+str,true);
```

validation of the input:

```
$v = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 
                   'v', 
                   FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                   array(
                         'flags'     => FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE, 
                         'options'   => array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 5)
                        ));
 if(!$v){exit();}
```

Answer (score 4):

Can't see anything wrong (as far as logic is concerned). So here is a vague debug answer:

First you should simply call your php script directly to see if and what it outputs:
http://localhost/thingy/include/ajax/rate.php?v=3

If that works, then the problem is your Javascript code. Try with jQuery just to be sure:

```
function addVote(n) {
    $('#txtHint').load("rate.php?v=" + n);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try put single quote in the query string's values:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO votes (title_id, score) VALUES ('1', '" . mysql_real_escape_string ($v) . "')";
```

and use

`mysql_real_escape_string (string $unescaped_string [, resource $link_identifier ]);`

on the variable to inject